# How to avoid html blocks with regex

Tags: html, regex

I have to find all the strings surrounded by "[" and "]" using regex, but avoiding the ones inside the `<table></table>` block, for example:

```
<html>
<body>
<p><table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td style="border-style: solid; border-width:1px;">
            <span style="font-family: Courier;">[data1]</span>
         </td>
         <td style="border-style: solid; border-width:1px;">
            <span style="font-family: Courier;">[data10]</span>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</p>
<p>[data3]&nbsp;&nbsp;[data4]&nbsp;&nbsp;[data5]</p>
</body>
</html>
```

in this case only [data3], [data4] and [data5] should be found.
So far I have this:
 `@"(((?<!<span>)(\[[a-zA-Z_0-9]+)](?!<\/span>))|((?<!<span>)(\[[a-zA-Z_0-9]+)])|((\[[a-zA-Z_0-9]+)](?!<\/span>)))(?!.*\1)"`
That finds all the [] blocks that are not surrounded by  tags and I tried adding a negative lookahead and lookbehind of  but it doesn't work, it stills gets the ones inside the table block.

Hope you guys can help me with this.

Comment: Obligatory link: [Do not use regex to parse HTML. TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1954610)

Comment: Which tool/language are you using? Using a regex to search the **inner-text only** (e.g. `"[data3]&nbsp;&nbsp;[data4]...."` is fine, but the first thing you need to do is parse the HTML - e.g. using an XPATH. Trying to do the whole search via regex is technically impossible; at best, you'll have an extremely complicated solution that works for *most* inputs - rather than a simple XPATH (or similar) that works for *all* inputs.

Comment: @TomLord What kind of URL is that? I thought my graphics card was on the blink for a sec!

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)
HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

Comment: @JGFMK It's called [Zalgo Text](https://lingojam.com/ZalgoText)

Comment: @TomLord Thank you, I will do it this way, I wanted to avoid using an external parser, but it seems like this will be the only approach

Answer (score -1):

Below regex will return your all [data] which enclose in `<p> </p>` tag.

```
/<p.*?>\[(.*?)\]<*.p>/g
```

so above regex will return this `<p>[data3]&nbsp;&nbsp;[data4]&nbsp;&nbsp;[data5]</p>` from your above HTML code.

When you get that string from above regex then use below regex to get only all [data] string.

```
/\[(.*?)\]/g
```

so above regex will return " [data3][data4][data5] " from above string.

Comment: This won't work for even the most trivial of variations. For example, if the input contains `<p>foo [data1] bar</p>` then the regex doesn't match.

Comment: It's a good example of why the golden advice is *don't use regex to parse HTML* (if you want a proper, comprehensive solution). You could keep making that regex increasingly complex trying to cover more edge cases, and I could keep giving more and more examples that still make it fail... Or, you could stop trying to do the whole thing in regex, an just use an HTML parser.

Comment: Your *second* pattern (`/\[(.*?)\]/g`) is perfectly fine for finding matches in the inner-text. But using regex to find that inner-text is a pathway to madness. (OP didn't even say that the text must be inside a `<p>` tag!! All they said is that it's *not* in a `<table>`.)

Comment: Yes, for HTML it's better to use parser instead of Regex.